# Export Test Case data from Kiwi Database to our system

Tags: kiwi-tcms

I'm running kiwi tcms using docker that connected with Postgres DB. I'm looking for how to export the test case, test plan, test run, and users from the postgre DB in docker container to our DB for backup purpose.  I can see this link,
https://tcms-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/tcms_api.html?highlight=rpc_client%20exec%20testcase

Here how the configuration detail would be for using from docker container on our own server?

Also, I hope this method returns all the test cases from Postgres DB, how can I filter the result between some dates

```
rpc_client.exec.TestCase.filter()
```

Answer (score 1):

To export all contents on your docker host execute:

`docker exec -it kiwi_web /Kiwi/manage.py dumpdata --all --indent 2 > database.json`

This will create a file named `database.json` in the current directory, outside of the running container!

See https://kiwitcms.org/blog/atodorov/2018/07/30/how-to-backup-docker-volumes-for-kiwi-tcms/ for additional info on how to backup uploads.

Comment: Thanks, But I would like to export the data using API call, as said in my question, pull the test cases data from the tables based by applying specific date ranges. How this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

From the same URL as posted above:
https://kiwitcms.org/blog/atodorov/2018/07/30/how-to-backup-docker-volumes-for-kiwi-tcms/

Postgres specific info:

```
docker exec -i kiwi_db /bin/bash -c 'pg_dump --dbname=kiwi -F c' > backup.bak
```